# My varnish devicedetect.vcl is not working site no longer responsive

Tags: redirect, cache, varnish, centos8

**default.vcl**

```
    # Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
    backend default {
        .host = "127.0.0.1";
        .port = "8080";
    }

    sub vcl_recv {
      # Set the X-Forwarded-For header so the backend can see the original
      # IP address. If one is already set by an upstream proxy, we'll just re-use that.

      #return(pass);

      if (req.method == "PURGE") {
         return (purge);
      }

      if (req.method == "XCGFULLBAN") {
         ban("req.http.host ~ .*");
         return (synth(200, "Full cache cleared"));
      }

      if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
         return(pass);
      }

      if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
         return (pass);
      }

      if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
         return (pass);
      }

      if (req.url ~ "(wp-admin|post\.php|edit\.php|wp-login|wp-json)") {
         return(pass);
      }

      if (req.url ~ "/wp-cron.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
         return (pass);
      }
      if (req.url ~ "/xmlrpc.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
         return (pass);
      }

      if ((req.http.host ~ "sitename.com" && req.url ~ "^some_specific_filename\.(css|js)")) {
         return (pass);
      }

    # Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages
    if (!(req.url ~ "(cart|my-account/*|wc-api*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|ask-question|product/*)")) {
    unset req.http.cookie;
    }
    # Pass through the WooCommerce dynamic pages
    if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account/*|checkout|wc-api/*|addons|logout|lost-password|ask-question|product/*)") {
    return (pass);
    }
    # Pass through the WooCommerce add to cart
    if (req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
    return (pass);
    }
    # Pass through the WooCommerce API
    if (req.url ~ "\?wc-api=" ) {
    return (pass);
    }

      set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");

      # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
      set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

      # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
      set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

      # Remove the wp test cookie
      set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

      # Remove the PHPSESSID in members area cookie
      set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "PHPSESSID=[^;]+(; )?", "");

      unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    sub vcl_purge {
        set req.method = "GET";
        set req.http.X-Purger = "Purged";

        #return (synth(200, "Purged"));
        return (restart);
    }

    sub vcl_backend_response {
        # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
        #
        # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
        # and other mistakes your backend does.

        set beresp.grace = 12h;
        set beresp.ttl = 12h;
    }

    sub vcl_deliver {
        # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
        # response to the client.
        #
        # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
    }

sub vcl_hash {
  if(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
  }
  if(req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "(mobile|tablet)") {
    hash_data("mobile");
  }
}
```

**devicedetect.vcl**

```
#
# Copyright (c) 2016-2018 Varnish Cache project
# Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Varnish Software AS
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-2-Clause
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
# 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
# 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
# ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
# ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL AUTHOR OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
# FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
# DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
# OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
# HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
# LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
# OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
# SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# detectdevice.vcl - regex based device detection for Varnish
# https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-devicedetect/
#
# Original author: Lasse Karstensen <lkarsten@varnish-software.com>

sub devicedetect {
    unset req.http.X-UA-Device;
    set req.http.X-UA-Device = "pc";

    # Handle that a cookie may override the detection alltogether.
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(?i)X-UA-Device-force") {
        /* ;?? means zero or one ;, non-greedy to match the first. */
        set req.http.X-UA-Device = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "(?i).*X-UA-Device-force=([^;]+);??.*", "\1");
        /* Clean up our mess in the cookie header */
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|; ) *X-UA-Device-force=[^;]+;? *", "\1");
        /* If the cookie header is now empty, or just whitespace, unset it. */
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^ *$") { unset req.http.Cookie; }
    } else {
        if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; \+http://www.google.com/bot.html\)" ||
            (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(Android|iPhone)" && req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible.?; Googlebot/2.1.?; \+http://www.google.com/bot.html") ||
            (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(iPhone|Windows Phone)" && req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible; bingbot/2.0; \+http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm")) {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-bot"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)(ads|google|bing|msn|yandex|baidu|ro|career|seznam|)bot" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)(baidu|jike|symantec)spider" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)pingdom" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)facebookexternalhit" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)scanner" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)slurp" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)(web)crawler") {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "bot"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ipad")        { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-ipad"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ip(hone|od)") { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-iphone"; }
        /* how do we differ between an android phone and an android tablet?
           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341637/how-do-detect-android-tablets-in-general-useragent */
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android.*(mobile|mini)") { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-android"; }
        // android 3/honeycomb was just about tablet-only, and any phones will probably handle a bigger page layout.
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android 3")              { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-android"; }
        /* Opera Mobile */
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Opera Mobi")                  { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smartphone"; }
        // May very well give false positives towards android tablets. Suggestions welcome.
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-android"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-rim"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "hp-tablet.*TouchPad")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-hp"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Kindle/3")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-kindle"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Touch.+Tablet PC" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "Windows NT [0-9.]+; ARM;" ) {
                set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-microsoft";
        }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Mobile.+Firefox")     { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-firefoxos"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "^HTC" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "Fennec" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "IEMobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "BlackBerry" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "BB10.*Mobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "GT-.*Build/GINGERBREAD" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "SymbianOS.*AppleWebKit") {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smartphone";
        }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)symbian" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^sonyericsson" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^nokia" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^samsung" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^lg" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)bada" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)blazer" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)cellphone" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)iemobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)midp-2.0" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)u990" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)netfront" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)opera mini" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)palm" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)nintendo wii" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)playstation portable" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)portalmmm" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)proxinet" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)windows\ ?ce" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)winwap" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)eudoraweb" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)htc" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)240x320" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)avantgo") {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-generic";
        }
    }
}
```

Site stopped being responsive after adding varnish

How can i fix the responsiveness of the site... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually forgot to mention that you need to perform `call devicedetect`.

Here's a snippet that should help:

```
include "devicedetect.vcl";
sub vcl_recv {
    call devicedetect;
}
```

Only when the `devicedetect` routine is called, that `X-UA-Device` will be set.